# How to apply Drop Shadow , Inner Shadow , Gradient Overlay Effect to TextBlock in wpf

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I have following effect to my PSD:-

==============Drop Shadow=============

-Blend Mode:- Multiply

-Color:- black

-Opacity :- 50%

-Angel :- 90

=========Inner Shadow================

-Blend Mode:- Normal

-Color:- White

-Opacity :- 62%

-Angel :- 120

=======Gradient Overlay===============

-Blend Mode:- Normal

-Opacity :- 100%

-Angel :- 90

-Start Color:- #8a8a8a

-End Color:- #ffffff

The Following is the Image from psd
[image]

How to apply to the Textblack i have apply the following code :-

```
<TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" Margin="5" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial Bold"
                            TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"  TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tournament: $3 + $0.30 KO Sit and Go">
                                    <TextBlock.Effect>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Opacity="50" Direction="-90" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="2" >

 </DropShadowEffect>
    </TextBlock.Effect>
     </TextBlock>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
Hi we can add the  Inner Shadow as follows

<Grid Height="100" Width="600" Margin="100,100,100,100">
        <Border Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
           BorderThickness="1" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" 
              BorderThickness="1" Margin="-2">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10">
                    </DropShadowEffect>
                </Border.Effect>

            <TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" Margin="5" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF" FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial Bold"
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"  TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tournament: $3 + $0.30 KO Sit and Go">
            <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Opacity="50" Direction="-90" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="2" >

                </DropShadowEffect>

            </TextBlock.Effect>

        </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Border> 

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    Hi  this may help you in adding inner shadow and gradient overlay effect to TextBlock                                                                                          


  <Grid Height="100" Width="600" Margin="100,100,100,100">
        <Border Background="LightGray" BorderBrush="DarkGray" 
           BorderThickness="1" ClipToBounds="True">
            <Border Background="Transparent" BorderBrush="Black" 
              BorderThickness="1" Margin="-2">
                <Border.Effect>
                    <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10">
                    </DropShadowEffect>
                </Border.Effect>

            <TextBlock x:Name="lblTitle" Margin="5"  FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="20" FontFamily="Arial Bold"
        TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"  TextAlignment="Left" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Tournament: $3 + $0.30 KO Sit and Go">
                    <TextBlock.Foreground>
                        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                            <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                            <GradientStop x:Name="WhiteOffset" Color="White" Offset="1"/>
                            <GradientStop x:Name="GrayOffset" Color="Gray" Offset="1"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </TextBlock.Foreground>
                    <TextBlock.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard Storyboard.TargetProperty="Offset" Duration="0:0:1" RepeatBehavior="Forever">
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="WhiteOffset" From="0" To="1" />
                                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="GrayOffset" From="0" To="1" />
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </TextBlock.Triggers>
                    <TextBlock.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect Color="Black" Opacity="50" Direction="-90" RenderingBias="Quality" ShadowDepth="2" >

                </DropShadowEffect>

            </TextBlock.Effect>

        </TextBlock>
            </Border>
        </Border> 

    </Grid>
```